# What is the cofinality of the empty set?

Tags: order-theory

The cofinality of a partially ordered set $P$ is the least cardinality of the cofinal subsets of $P$. But since the empty set has no cofinal subsets, what is the cofinality of the empty set?

Comment: On the contrary, *every* subset of the emptyset is cofinal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty set has exactly one cofinal subset, namely itself.  So the cofinality of the empty set is $0$.